# optimizing less than query

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

All tables used have millions of records.
c.periodseq and c.VALIDTRANSACTION  are not indexed and I cannot index it as its a prod table which cannot be modified. The '<' operator is making the query very slow. Please suggest an alternative.

```
  SELECT V.EVENTTYPEID, C.CREDITTYPEID
  FROM CREDIT C,
       VALIDTRANSACTION V
  WHERE V.VALIDTRANSACTIONSEQ = C.VALIDTRANSACTIONSEQ
    and c.periodseq <1055;
```

[image]

Comment: I can not really see how you would be able to optimize this without creating an index.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN PLAN` tell you about that query?

Comment: If your picture is showing the actual plan, then it *is* using an index. The CBO decided to use a fast full scan due to the expected cardinality of the row source. If this query is a production app's query and someone picks a recent reporting period, then they will essentially be extracting millions and millions of rows. There's not much you can do to optimize a ridiculous operation.